# calling alloca( ) from another function call parameter?

Tags: linux, malloc, alloca

Why calling `alloc( )` as a parameter to another function call like this `func(x, alloca(size), z);` is considered wrong According to a book called `the linux programming interface`

> This is because the stack space allocated by alloca() would appear in the middle of
> the space for the function arguments (which are placed at fixed locations within the
> stack frame). Instead, we must use code such as this:
>
> ```
>   void *y; 
>   y = alloca(size); 
>   func(x, y, z);
> ```

while This is wrong

```
func(x, alloca(size), z);  /* WRONG! */
```

isn't those 2 pieces are supposed to be equivelent .In the first one `alloca` is called first then `func` is called with it's return value, so if someone can explain how `alloca` allocate memory on stack that make both approaches different.

Comment: Is there any reasoning why it's "wrong"? Terms "right"/"wrong" are subjective. Is it "wrong" just because there are two function calls on the same line which doesn't follow some code style?

Comment: @KamilCuk it's according to a book called ```the linux programming interface``` gonna edit the question by a quote from the book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alloca` man page mentions this in the BUGS section:

> On many systems alloca() cannot be used inside the list of arguments
> of a function call, because the stack space reserved by alloca()
> would appear on the stack in the middle of the space for the function
> arguments.

E.g. in `func(x, alloca(1000), z);` you might end with a stack layout like

```
 sp+100c:    x
 sp+1008:    .... space reserved by alloca
 sp+   8:
 sp+   4:    sp+8 (return value of alloca())
 sp+   0:    z
```

Common ABIs require that parameters of `func(void *, void *, void *)` are at the locations `[sp + 0]`, `[sp + 4]` and `[sp + 8]`.  There is expected a layout similarly to

```
 sp+100c:    .... end of space reserved by alloca
 sp+   c:    .... space reserved by alloca
 sp+   8:    x
 sp+   4:    sp+0x0c (return value of alloc())
 sp+   0:    z
```

Comment: So, is this is a BUG that will be fixed and has nothing to do with how ```alloc( )``` is supposed to work ?

Comment: `alloca` is supposed to work by extending the stack; there is no exact specification how this shall happen.  Most/all existing implementations suffer from certain (design) bugs (e.g. the actual issue or behaviour in error case) and I would not expect that these get fixed.  You have to be carefully when `alloca()`.

Comment: Did you assume the stack grows from bottom? How the parameters are pushed into stack(the order which they pushed into stack)? Could you explain 'why' in detail?

Comment: In given example, stack grows from top to bottom and parameters are filled in the given order (first `x`, then `alloca()`, then the result of `alloca()` and last `z`).

Comment: @ensc But i don't still understand why the stack layout is bad(`"because the stack space reserved by alloca() would appear on the stack in the middle of the space for the function arguments."`). The compiler couldn't determine the location of parameter `z` because of allocated memory spreaded from `sp+1008` to `sp+8`?